# How to override React Component styles with styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, styled-components

I have a `<DiscoverButton>` React Component which has some styles and does smth when clicked. I'm using styled components for styling btw. I need to create a `<ReturnButton>` React Component which will be almost identical, the only difference being the width.

This is what I'm trying to do, but doesn't accomplish what I want:

`DiscoverButton.tsx`

```
export const BigButton = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: var(--lighter-black);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  color: var(--cultured-white);

  transition: background-color 0.7s, color 0.7s;

  &:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid var(--lighter-black);
    color: var(--lighter-black);
  }
`;

export const DiscoverButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <BigButton onClick={() => // do smth with props >
      {children}
    </BigButton>
  );
};
```

And here is where I struggle:
`ReturnButton.tsx`:

```
const ReturnButtonStyled = styled(DiscoverButton)`
  width: 7%;
`;

export const ReturnButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <ReturnButtonStyled id={props.id} btnTitle={props.btnTitle}>
      {children}
    </ReturnButtonStyled>
  );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the `className` prop through to the rendered styled component.

```
export const DiscoverButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <BigButton
      className={className}
      onClick={() => // do smth with props
    >
      {children}
    </BigButton>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-override-react-component-styles-with-styled-components]

[image]

### Update

[Caveat with `className`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#caveat-with-classname)

> When defining a component you will need to mark `className` as
> optional in your Props interface

```
interface Props {
  .... other prop types ....
  /* This prop is optional, since TypeScript won't know that it's passed by the wrapper */
  className?: string,
  .... other prop types ....
}
```

You also don't necessarily need to write your functional components in such a way as to manually pass the extraneous props on to the styled components.

Example:

```
interface Props {
  btnTitle?: string,
  children: any,
  className?: string,
  id?: string,
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>,
}

const BigButton = styled.button`
  .... base styles ....
`;

const DiscoverButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, className, onClick }) => (
  <BigButton
    className={className}
    onClick={(...args) => {
      console.log("Did something with the props");
      onClick(...args);
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </BigButton>
);

const ReturnButton: React.FC<Props> = styled(DiscoverButton)`
  width: 7%;
`;
```

[image: Edit how-to-override-react-component-styles-with-styled-components (typescript)]

Comment: Thank you. It works, but TypeScript is not happy. How should I define my `Props` interface ? Should it contain `className: string` ? If I do so, then I'll need to pass a className whenever I use my `<DiscoverButton>` Component.

Comment: @sleepydrmike I think you declare the `className` prop as optional on your `props` interface, i.e. `className?: string`. Also, it wasn't clear if you've any "business" logic between the `DiscoverButton` and `ReturnButton` declarations and the returns of `BigButton` and `ReturnButtonStyled`, but because of the way you've defined the component bodies is why you need to proxy the `className` prop through. I'll investigate a version where you may not need to do this.